# Eclipse with Papyrus OCL based JAVA code generation

Tags: java, eclipse, uml, ocl, papyrus

I have created UML Class Diagram using Eclipse and Papyrus plugin.

[image]

In separate file I have defined OCL constraints

```
import 'model.uml'

package Shop

    context Product

    inv PriceIsNotNegative:
    self.price > 0

endpackage
```

I am trying to generate JAVA classes (left click > Designer > Generate Java Classes), but recently generated JAVA classes doesn't contain any sign of defined constraints. Where could be the problem?